# Read in a file and set fields as variables in R

Tags: r, environment-variables, assign, do.call

I am trying to read in a file and have R set each data pair as an environmental variable.

I have an input file that comes from the web with the data below. It has both numeric and character variables that need to be read in. This is where I am getting hung up, as I can only seem to bring them in as one or the other, which makes assign, or do.call error out when it hits characters that are classified as numeric, or vice versa.

Any ideas?

```
input file "input":
user <- "johndoe", date <- "1-30-2019", run <- 1, scoring <- "default", 
high_cutoff <- 70, low_cutoff <- 15, bg1 <- 12, bg2 <- 12, bg3 <- 12, 
group_cut <- 60, stbg <- "no", factor <- 25, rest <- 2, 
loo_enable <- "no"

wd <- getwd() 
phpvars <- as.data.frame(t(read.table(paste0(wd, "/input"), sep = ",")))


#attempt 1 - reads everything in as character
for (i in phpvars$V1){
 x<- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(i," <- ")))
 assign(x[1,1],(x[1,2]))
}

#attempt 2 - tries to detect type of each data point as it comes in, and 
#assign as. (numeric or character)

for (i in phpvars$V1){
 x<- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(i," <- ")))
 type <- typeof(x[1,2])
 d <- paste0("as.", type)
 e <- x[1,2]
 assign(x[1,1],paste(d,(e)))
 }



#alternate to assign - has same problems though
do.call("<-",list(x[1,1],x[1,2]))
```

Desired Output as environmental variables:

```
 user <- "johndoe"
 date <- "1-30-2019"
 run <- 1
 scoring <- "default"
 high_cutoff <- 70
 low_cutoff <- 15
 bg1 <- 12
 bg2 <- 12
 bg3 <- 12
 group_cut <- 60
 stbg <- "no"
 factor <- 25
 rest <- 2
 loo_enable <- "no"
```

Is there a way (better way) to read in data and set them as environmental variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a great quoted input. Take advantage of that by specifying that your input string is quoted with `quote = ""` argument upon using `read.table()` function:

```
wd <- getwd() 
phpvars <- as.data.frame( t( read.table( paste0(wd, "/input") ,
                                         sep = ",",   
                                         quote = "" ) ) )
```

Then you just have to parse each row of `phpvars` table and evaluated them by using `parse()` and `eval()` functions respectively:

```
 for(i in phpvars$V1){

     eval( parse( text = as.character(i) ) )
 }
```

Comment: If your input file had not been quoted, you can always use `grepl(pattern = "[0-9]+", x = your_string)` for evaluating whether your values are character or numeric class after splitting each row in function of `" <- "` (i.e. `sep = " <- "` argument)